# How to label one specific scatter point (not all points) using d3 or regular javascript?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The annotation should read “min y-value: ” where  is the minimum y. I wrote the following codes which labels the same smallest y value to all points but I want the label only displaying on the one scatter point who has the smallest y value

Please help!

```
var min = d3.min(dataset, function(d) { return d3.min(d); });
svg.selectAll("text")
   .data(dataset)
   .enter()       
   .append("text")
   .text(function(d) {return "min y-value"+min;})
   .attr("x", function(d) {return xScale(d[0]);})
   .attr("y", function(d) {return yScale(d[1]);})
```

Comment: Should not be min = d3.min(dataset, function(d) { return d[1]; } I mean minimum y value only (no need of x value) ?

Comment: min = d3.min(dataset, function(d) { return d[1]; }  does it choose the minimum value (xMin, yMin) by smallest x value or smallest y value in the array of array?

Comment: Self-vandalism rolled back. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209436/self-vandalism-what-is-correct-action

Answer (score 0):

You could add a filter in order to only show the text on certain data elements.

```
// If you really want the min of y-values - is it 
// possible that you meant d[1] in the following min function?
var min = d3.min(dataset, function(d) { return d[1]; });
svg.selectAll("text")
   .data(dataset)
   .enter()
   .filter(function(d) { return d3.min(d) > min })
   .append("text")
   .text(function(d) {return "min y-value"+min;})
   .attr("x", function(d) {return xScale(d[0]);})
   .attr("y", function(d) {return yScale(d[1]);})
```